# UISlider controlling UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uislider

I'm trying to make a `UISlider` control the picture shown in a `UIImageView`. Slider min is 0, max is 50.

The problem is the `UIImageView` only react to the `else` and `chosenTime = 50`.
Only then corresponding picture are shown in the `UIImageView`.
48 and 49 are ignored, the "else" picture is shown in these cases.
Any help is much appreciated!

Here's the code:

```
-(IBAction) sliderChanged:(id)sender{
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *) sender;
    int prog = (int)(slider.value + 0.5f);
    NSString * newText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", prog];
    sliderLabel.text = newText;
    int chosenTime = [newText intValue];

    NSLog(@"chosenTime is %i", chosenTime);
    //chosenTime is confirmed int value in the NSLOG!!!

    if (chosenTime == 1) {
        NSString *fullpath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/Pic0001.png"];
        clockView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullpath];
    }
    if (chosenTime == 48) {
        NSString *fullpath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/Pic0048.png"];
        clockView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullpath];
    } 
    if (chosenTime == 49) {
        NSString *fullpath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/Pic0049.png"];
        clockView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullpath];
    } 
    if (chosenTime == 50) {
        NSString *fullpath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/Pic0050.png"];
        clockView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullpath];
    } else {
        NSString *fullpath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/Pic0000.png"];
        clockView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullpath];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified the code a little bit. Make sure the NSLogged numbers are in the range 1-50. If not, the slider's minimum/maximum values are misconfigured.

```
-(IBAction) sliderChanged: (UISlider *) sender
{
    int chosenTime = (int) ceilf(slider.value);
    NSLog(@"chosenTime is %i", chosenTime);
    //chosenTime is confirmed int value in the NSLOG!!!

    if (chosenTime > 50)
        chosenTime = 0;

    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Pic00%02d.png", chosenTime];
    NSString *fullpath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent: fileName];
    clockView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: fullpath];
}
```

The problem with your code is the absence of `else` after each `if`. The comparisons fall through to the last `if`, after which it's either 50 or not 50, and not being 50 is treated as zero.